# How to write unit tests for PDF Kit for node js?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, pdfkit

I'm writing a pdf generator using https://github.com/foliojs/pdfkit inside a hapi server route, I have successfully implemented it but I'm struggling on writing the unit tests for it.

I've googled this but I have not had found any answer yet and package's documentation doesn't mention anything about testing.

Anyone have written unit test for his library?

Thanks for your help y'all!

Edit: The focus of the test is how 'doc', an instance of pdfkit, works here is the function i want to test, the functions that are not added are just separation of some repetitive pdf code

```
const generatePdf = async (request, h) => {
return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
        const doc = initPdf();
        const {curated, address, photo} = await dataHandler(request, h);

        // Title page
        doc.font('Lato-Semibold')
            .fontSize(16)
            .text(
                `${address.address1}, ${address.city} ${address.stateProvince} ${address.postalCode}`,
                {align: 'center'}
            );
        doc.fontSize(14).text(' ');

        if (photo.base64Photo) {
            handleImage(doc, photo.base64Photo);
        }

        // Others page(s)
        doc.addPage();

        renderSections(doc, curated.others);

        // Amenities page(s)
        doc.addPage();

        doc.font('Lato-Semibold')
            .fontSize(26)
            .text(
                await getTranslatedString(
                    locale,
                    `px-hospitality.amenity.category.AMENITIES`
                ),
                {align: 'center'}
            );

        // Hack to add a space between text and next header
        doc.fontSize(14).text(' ');
        renderSections(doc, curated.amenities);

        generatePageNumbers(doc);

        // write to PDF
        const chunks = []; // contains the base64 string

        doc.on('data', (chunk) => {
            chunks.push(chunk);
        });

        doc.on('end', () => {
            // the stream is at its end, so push the resulting base64 string to the response
            const result = Buffer.concat(chunks);
            resolve({code: 200, result});
        });

        doc.on('error', (err) => {
            reject({code: 500, error});
        });
        doc.end(); // will trigger the stream to end
    } catch (error) {
        reject({code: 500, error});
    }
});
```

};

Comment: Please add the code under test in your post.

Comment: @slideshowp2 Done!